# COUNT with CASE in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to take count of data from one table and if count is more than 1  need to get result as 'YES' and count equal to 1 I need to get result as 'NO'.

Query :

```
Select item,
       case
         when count( item_des) > 1
         then 'REassigned Yes'
         when count(item_des) = 1
         then 'REassigned NO' else 'N/A' end 
       from material
       where item  in ('23','24,'25') and item_des like ('Cpu%to%move%')
       group by item;
```

Each item number has multiple entries with `items_des` column, and I need to take count of `item_des` column where `item_des like ('Cpu%to%move%')` and do the count and print the result based on the count.

Comment: What is the problem with the query you've shown? It seems to do what you're asking. With no raw data, expected results or current output it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is that your current query doesn't ever show 'N/A', because the filter excludes any items which don't have any matching descriptions, then as @Tajesh says you can move the condition. You can still do a count though, which seems more logical:

```
select item,
  case
    when count(case when item_des like 'Cpu%to%move%' then item_des end) > 1
    then 'REassigned Yes'
    when count(case when item_des like 'Cpu%to%move%' then item_des end) = 1
    then 'REassigned NO'
    else 'N/A'
  end
from material
where item  in ('23', '24', '25')
group by item;
```

The inner `case when item_des like 'Cpu%to%move%' then item_des end` has an implicit `else null`, but you can make it explicit if you prefer. The `count()` function does not count nulls, so this only counts rows where the description matches the pattern - those that don't resolve to null, which isn't included in the count.

If `item` is a number then the filter should be:

```
where item  in (23, 24, 25)
```

If you don't want to repeat the inner case logic then you can use a CTE or line view:

```
select item,
  case
    when cnt > 1 then 'REassigned Yes'
    when cnt = 1 then 'REassigned NO'
    else 'N/A'
  end
from (
  select item,
    count(case when item_des like 'Cpu%to%move%' then item_des end) as cnt
  from material
  where item  in (23, 24, 25)
  group by item
)
```

You still won't see anything if an item doesn't appear in the table at all; there are ways around that but it isn't clear if it can happen, or what you want to see if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
case
when sum(case when item_des like ('Cpu%to%move%') then 1 else 0 end) > 1
then 'REassigned Yes'
when sum(case when item_des like ('Cpu%to%move%') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
then 'REassigned NO' 
else 'N/A' end
```

Comment: It might not be obvious to the OP that the condition needs to be removed from the `where` clause to see this have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select . . . ,
       (case when count(*) > 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end)
```

Comment: i have re arranged my question , please help me with that